# How to order in google analytics v4?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-analytics-data-api

I am trying to run this query order by date, the default value is ordered by screenviews what makes a strange chart. So I am trying to sort it by date.

```
let rst = await analytics.runReport({
  property: `properties/${property}`,
  dateRanges: [{
    startDate: '30daysAgo',
    endDate: 'today'
  }],
  dimensions:[
    {
      name: 'date'
    }
  ],
  metrics:[
    {
      name: 'screenPageViews'
    }
  ],
        orderBys:[
            {
                fieldName: 'date'
            }
        ]
});
```

But I am getting the following error

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field  exists in OrderBy but is not defined in input Dimensions/Metrics list

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics) it doesnt mention anything about order by.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

```
rst = await analytics.runReport({
  property: `properties/${property}`,
  dateRanges: [{
    startDate: '30daysAgo',
    endDate: 'today'
  }],
  dimensions:[
    {
      name: 'date'
    }
  ],
  metrics:[
    {
      name: 'screenPageViews'
    }
  ],
        orderBys:[
            {dimension:{
                    dimensionName: 'date'
                } 
            }
        ]
});
```